# Не могу понять где ошибка в запросе?

Tags: php, sql

```
$token = $_GET["token"]; //принимает значения, проверял.

// а вот тут не работает, почему?
$row = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'Tokens'('token') VALUES('$token')");
```

Comment: С таким построением запросов к базе вас взломают за 5 минут. И функции `mysql_` устарели уже в PHP 5.5.

Comment: Вы открыли соединение к базе через mysql_connect или просто опустили часть кода?

Comment: Какие поля есть ещё в таблице токенов? Возможно, что вы не заполнили все обязательные поля.

Comment: @AK только одно поле, код опустил)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, как правильно указано в другом ответе, надо учить синтаксис SQL. Чтобы по крайней мере отличать строку от *идентификатора*.

Во-вторых, для работы с БД надо использовать ПДО. И код тогда будет таким:

```
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Tokens (token) VALUES(?)")->execute([$_GET["token"]]);
```

Comment: Что означает знак вопроса?

Comment: Вопрос о том где ошибка в запросе о не о том что использовать для запроса

Comment: VALUES(?) почему здесь знак вопроса?

Comment: @MartinezToni Знак вопроса означает переменную в SQLзапросе. Данные в запрос всегда надо передавать не напрямую, а через такие переменные, они называются плейсхолдерами.

Comment: Если я подставлю свою переменную $token вместо "знака вопроса", то это ясно, но что в такому случае означает >execute([$_GET["token"]]);

Comment: Это передача значения для переменной.

Comment: прочитал мануал,   просто выполняем метод execute(), передав ему массив со значением полученным в гет-запросе)

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Comment: Сервер выкидывает ошибку 500

Comment: @Ипатьев почему?)

Comment: @Ипатьев уже и подключился через pdo, все равно ошибка 500

Comment: @MartinezToni ошибку надо смотреть в логе сервера. Или, чтобы РНР показывал ошибки на экране, надо его настроить как написано здесь; http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Answer (score 2):

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)

прочтите синтаксис использования команды

http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html

Comment: $row = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Tokens(token) VALUES($token)");

По вашему вот так?

Comment: если у вас таблица называется Tokens (без приставки tbl_ или любого другого префикса) то да , только пробел поставьте после названия таблицы